# Proving $\mathbb P$ is denumerable.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

To prove that a set $A$ is denumerable we must find a function $f:\mathbb N\to A$, s.t $f$ is bijective.

In my textbook there is this proof that the set of all primes is denumerable,

let $f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb P$, s.t $f(1)=2$, and for $n\ge1$ $$f(n+1)=\text{the least prime }>f(n)$$

but why can't we just define $f$ as $$f(n)=\text{the nth prime}$$

Comment: For both definitions; how would you formalize this definition?

Comment: What do you mean by formalizing? @Servaes

Comment: text definition and yours look synonymous.

Answer (score 0):

The text definition is the same as yours! What could you possibly mean by “the $n$th prime” besides an inductive definition like “the next prime after the $(n-1)$st prime”, which is essentially the given textbook definition?

Either definition, of course, relies on the fact that a “next prime” always exists, but presumably you are familiar with at least one [proof of that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem).